# Trailing space inside style tag

Tags: html, semantic-markup

This one has trailing space inside the tag

```
The quick brown <strong>fox jumps </strong>over the lazy dog
```

where, this has not.

```
The quick brown <strong>fox jumps</strong> over the lazy dog
```

The thing is, `<strong/>` tag works ok, the space doesn't get bolded, but the problem comes with underlines.

```
The quick brown <u>fox jumps </u>over the lazy dog
```

results in a underline applied to space, which doesn't seem very "correct" to me.

But the reason why I'm asking this, is because, by default, when you select (double-click) a word within text, the trailing space is always taken into selection (at least on Windows). And that results in a wrongly applied underline.

So, which is more correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should only add the tag to the text you want. Without the space that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows' selection algorithm is horribly broken - i'm coming up against this problem all the time with users of our CMS. Do you want that space underlined? Probably not. Therefore, the former is 'correct'.

Comment: Sadly, but Windows' itself is horribly broken.

Comment: Well, yeah, but we need to narrow down the problem space *slightly* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that a "whitespace" is a character so when you leave a space between a word inside a tag, that whitespace also inherits the property that you're trying to apply.

Here is a breakdown on how whitespace is set.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character